# Is it possible to do some function beforePageLoad and afterPage load with nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

So I'm creating the app in nuxt.js and a would like to create the preloading screen that is same for all the pages.
When doing this with standard vue-router I used just add the following to router.js

```
//router.js

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

    router.loading = true
    setTimeout(() => next(), 300)

})

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    setTimeout(() => router.loading = false, 300)
})
```

Is it possible to do something similar in nuxt.js?

Comment: Maybe you need this: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading-indicator/

Comment: Thanks for help but that is not what i'm looking for. I have custom loading screen that should be triggered every time i page is changed.The loading indicator Property will only run first time user enter. I also tried this https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading/ but I don't like setup and it doesn't work when page load. Everything i try look to complicated and dirty compare to standard vue-router solution